# php reading exif orientation returns '...' while it should be 8 (90 degrees)

Tags: php, android

I have a site where you can upload photos. when they are shot in portrait, they are shown in landscape 90 degrees to the left, so they must be rotated 90 degrees to the right. my script:

```
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $rotated = false;
            $exif = exif_read_data($uploadedfile);
            $orientation = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
            switch($orientation) {
            case 3:
                $src = imagerotate($src, 180, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $src = imagerotate($src, -90, 0);
                    $rotated = true;
                break;
            case 8:
                $src = imagerotate($src, 90, 0);
                $rotated = true;
                break;
            }
```

But the value of $orientation is '...' .
I am uploading photo's from my samsung galaxy s6, but the photo's from the galaxy s3 have the same wrong orientation.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Show your uploading code. Big chance you do it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php > $exif = exif_read_data('20160305_073024.jpg');
php > print_r($exif);
Array
(
    [FileName] => 20160305_073024.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1458474774
    [FileSize] => 148254
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="600" height="860"
            [Height] => 860
            [Width] => 600
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 1
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/2.8
            [UserComment] => User comments
            [UserCommentEncoding] => ASCII
        )

    [Make] => SAMSUNG
    [Model] => GT-N7100
    [Orientation] => 1
    [XResolution] => 72/1
    [YResolution] => 72/1
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => N7100XXUFNG4
    [DateTime] => 2016:03:05 07:30:24
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 190
    [ExposureTime] => 1/100
    [FNumber] => 14/5
    [ExposureProgram] => 3
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 100
    [ExifVersion] => 0220
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2016:03:05 07:30:24
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 2016:03:05 07:30:24
    [ComponentsConfiguration] => 
    [ExposureBiasValue] => 0/1
    [MeteringMode] => 2
    [FocalLength] => 5/2
    [UserComment] => ASCIIUser comments
    [FlashPixVersion] => 0100
    [ColorSpace] => 1
    [ExifImageWidth] => 600
    [ExifImageLength] => 860
    [ExposureMode] => 0
    [WhiteBalance] => 0
    [SceneCaptureType] => 0
    [ImageUniqueID] => S5K6A3
)
```

there is no `IFD0` key in the array returned by `exif_read_data`.
so you should replace your `$orientation` with

`$orientation = $exif['Orientation'];`